# What does the "Ice" word means in terms of Netrunner's Lore?

Tags: android-netrunner, game-lore

Why defending programs in the game of Android Netrunner are called Ice? Is it an acronym? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ice stands for "intrusion countermeasures electronics", a term
> popularized by William Gibson.

— Android Netrunner Comprehensive Unofficial Rules Wiki entry for [Ice](https://ancur.fandom.com/wiki/Ice)

Answer (score 5):

According to the original Netrunner rulebook (and as recorded in the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_Countermeasures_Electronics#Card_games) ):

The corps in Netrunner view it as an acronym for Intrusion Countermeasure Electronics.

The runners view it as an acronym for Insidious Cortical Electrocution.

The [original rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20160420132954/http://www.netrunneronline.com/rules/?s=1) included it in the corp (runner) glossary thus:

> Ice: A program that protects our data forts from intrusion. An acronym for "intrusion countermeasures electronics." (An acronym for "insidious cortical electrocution.")